# JavaFX KeyEvent setOnKeyPressed only works for buttons? Doesn't work for circle

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent

I have a code that works with button but not with circle.

What I want to do is to perform certain action after user pressed a button on keyboard. This code below works just with button. Just change circle to button (twice) to see it works. Is it not proper code to use for anything else?

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        Button button = new Button("Press Me!");



        //circle
        Circle circle = new Circle(); 

      //Setting the position of the circle 
      circle.setCenterX(300.0f); 
      circle.setCenterY(135.0f); 

      //Setting the radius of the circle 
      circle.setRadius(25.0f);  

      //Setting the color of the circle 
      circle.setFill(Color.BROWN); 

      //Setting the stroke width of the circle 
      circle.setStrokeWidth(20);    


                pane.setCenter(circle); // JUST CHANGE HERE (circle) to (button) to make it work
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        circle.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() { /////and HERE

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    System.out.println("Enter Pressed");
                }
            }
        });



    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onKeyPressedProperty): "Defines a function to be called when this Node or its child Node has input focus and a key has been pressed." How does a circle get input focus?

Comment: @James_D Ohh my fault for not spotting that. I guess all I have to do is to look at documentation.

Comment: Probably what you really need to do is clarify to yourself what you're *really* trying to do. It probably doesn't make sense for a circle to have input focus (unless you are implementing some kind of custom selection for the circle and other components in the UI). Consequently, it doesn't make sense to associate a key event handler with the circle.

Comment: I have done this step. The circle is the player. It should move each time he presses arrow keys. Im learning about keyevents and thought this code will help me.

Comment: Your confusing "what happens when a user event occurs" with "what is the event that occurs". The event doesn't happen "on the circle". The circle is just the thing you change when the event occurs.